# How to make an input be only numbers and not allow a more than a certain amount of characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I am writing a short program where the user has to guess a random number between 1-999 and then you are told if your guess is lower or higher than the random generated by the computer. I want to make it so that i this code

```
guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number, 1-999"))
```

If the number of characters typed in is more than 3, I want to delete the last number typed in.

For example if 4563 is the input, I want the program to delete the 3 and make the number 456.

Also, I want to make it so if someone inputs `a`, it will not be accepted.

**Edit** here's the full code

```
from random import randint
randNum = randint(1,999)
guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number, 1-999"))
tries = 1
while guess != randNum:
    tries += 1
    if guess > randNum:
        print "Guess lower"
    elif guess < randNum:
        print "Guess higher"
    guess = int(raw_input("Guess a number, 1-999"))
print "You guessed the right number in " + str(tries) + " tries"
```

I want the `guess` variable to be the one that only takes numbers with at least 1 and 3 or less digits.

**Edit**

I want to have something similar to the game [Oregon Trail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Oregon_Trail_(video_game)) where during rest stops, you can only type in numbers 1-9 and in any other input, the second number or any letters is deleted.

Comment: start by writing a code that does something, and then someone here can help, none will write the program for you.

Comment: You appear to have made no effort to implement what you describe. This isn't a code-writing service; **try something**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
s = input("My input ") # for 2.x it will be raw_input    
s = int(s) if len(s) <= 3 else int(s[0:3])
```

Comment: Why convert `[raw_]input` (which is **already a string**) with `str`?

Comment: and what if put aaa ^_^ you have to control that the user dident something else than digits!

Answer (score 0):

If you want cut only numbers from string, you can use regexp like that:

```
import re

digits = re.findall('\d', 'asdf23432asdf23') # find all digits in string
number = int(''.join(digits))
```

If you want to cut last numbers from int:

```
number = ''.join(digits) # join chars to string
if len(number) > 3:
    number = number[:3]

number = int(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're thinking the right way. When the user gives you bad input, don't try to guess what he meant. Just shout at him and let him try again :) You'll have to wrap the `int(...)` call in a `try` block to prevent errors from inputs like `"foobar"`, and then check if the input is between 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 0):

lazy way:

you do two controls, length and type:

```
if len(number) in [1, 2, 3] : # changed from <= because 0 is less than 3 ...
    try:
        number = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print 'we need numbers!'
else:
    print '3 chars only!'
```

Comment: Why you use "len(number) in [1, 2, 3]" instead "len(number) < 4"?

Comment: a user can input nothing, i already used <=3 but changed it in case someone put something empty

Comment: I think more pythonic will be "if number and len(number) < 4"

Comment: yes, 1 AND 1 will be 1, and more mathematic, i just wanted to show something else :D

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be:

```
import re
number = int(re.sub('\D', '', raw_input("Guess a number, 1-999: "))[:3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Python3 way...

```
from random import randint

def getGuess():
    while True:
        guess = input("Guess a number, 1-999\t\t")
        valid = errorCheck(guess)
        if valid == True:
            return int(guess)
        else:
            pass

def errorCheck(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input, not an integer")
    if x in list(range (1, 999)):
        return True
    else:
        print()
        print("Input is not within the data range.")
        return False

randNum = randint(1,999)
tries = 0
while True:
    guess = getGuess()
    tries += 1
    if guess > randNum:
        print ("Guess lower")
    elif guess < randNum:
        print ("Guess higher")
    else:
        print ("You guessed the right number in ", str(tries), " tries")
        break
```